# Displaying an admin message on woocommerce_order_action hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, orders

I used this code :

https://gist.github.com/bekarice/5233ed58c3a836064123b290463241c0

In **`sv_wc_process_order_meta_box_action`** function, how is possible to display a message box to admin?

Currently code uses **`update_post_meta()`** function and **`add_order_note()`** method and not display any message to admin.

Thanks.

Comment: Is better to include the code in your question with a link to the source and mentioning the author (just an advice).

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know is to use custom functions with the **`admin_notices`** action hook. So you could try to include the related **`add_action()`** inside the code you are using.

This code is untested, and I don't guarantee anything:

```php
// The message function to be hooked in 'admin_notices' hook.
function my_custom_admin_notice() { 
    ?>  
    <div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">
        <p><?php _e('Order has been updated "printed for packaging"'); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php 
}


//The second function that you use (customized with an add_action()):
function sv_wc_process_order_meta_box_action( $order ) {

    // add the order note
    $message = sprintf( __( 'Order information printed by %s for packaging.', 'my-textdomain' ), wp_get_current_user()->display_name );
    $order->add_order_note( $message );

    // add the flag so this action won't be shown again
    update_post_meta( $order->id, '_wc_order_marked_printed_for_packaging', 'yes' );

    // Setting the admin message function in 'admin_notices' hook.
    add_action('admin_notices', 'my_custom_admin_notice');
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_action_wc_custom_order_action', 'sv_wc_process_order_meta_box_action' );
```

---

Related documentation:

- [Complete Guide to WordPress Admin Notices](https://digwp.com/2016/05/wordpress-admin-notices/)
- [How to Add Admin Alerts and Error Messages to the Backend of WordPress](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/adding-admin-notices/)